# Return statement in `finally` overrides return statement in `try`

Tags: javascript, try-catch, try-catch-finally, try-finally

I've run into some problems in my code, and so I have narrowed it down to this simple use-case:

```
function func() {
    try {
        return true;
    }
    finally {
        return false;
    }
}

console.log(func());
```

To my extreme surprise, the printout of the code above is `false`.

Now, I could easily solve it with:

```
function func() {
    try {
        return true;
    }
    catch (error) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

In fact, that was my original code, but then I figured it would look nicer with `finally`.

I have read [this MDN post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#Description), which gives three forms for the `try` statement:

1. `try`...`catch`
2. `try`...`finally`
3. `try`...`catch`...`finally`

The 2nd form looks perfect for my use-case.

I am finding it extremely bewildering that the return statement in the `finally` part "overrides" the return statement in the `try` part.

In fact, I am not even sure how this behavior is achieved via "compilation" (double quoting, because I know that this term doesn't really apply for Javascript).

Common sense tells me that the code inside the `finally` part is placed at the end of the `try` part and (optionally) at the end of the `catch` part.

In fact, I'm pretty sure that this is the case in compiled languages like C++ and Java, though for the sake of my question, it is not really important whether or not this is how `finally` is implemented behind the scene.

My question - how is it possible for the return statement of the `try` part to be so brutally ignored here? What have I missed about `finally`?

Comment: *"What have I missed about `finally`?"* Finally is **guaranteed** to be executed, even after a `return` or an `Error`. How would **you** solve this problem in your snippet? Returning twice in the same function call; because again, the second `return` is guaranteed to be executed even after the first `return`.